# Newline for Django form field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, backend

I am  using `{{ FORM | linebreaks}}` in templates, but this code put `<br>` in my textarea...

[image]

my forms.py codes:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    FirstName = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
        label=''
    )
    LastName = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
        label=''
    )
    Email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Email'}),
        label=''
    )
    Message = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Message'}),
        label=''
    )
```

i send this to views and send it with context to html page.

Comment: Are you using crispy forms here? (Looks a little like it). Can you post code showing how you're setting your placeholder text for everything?

Comment: Message = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Message'}),
        label=' '
    )

Comment: I don't see a problem there - could you add your form code to the question please.

Comment: this problem is only in "Textarea", when i change it to "TextInput" problem is solved.....but i need "Textarea" :(

Comment: That's really odd. You have no methods on the form that could be overriding this? What happens if you inspect the page - what does the html look like? Can you try `{{ FORM | linebreaks|force_escape }}` and see what is displayed?

Comment: puted <br> between Textarea tags...

Comment: You mean no change? OK, then I got no other suggestions - I was thinking you might have copy/pasted a hidden character in there somewhere that was confusing things. But maybe not.

Comment: That time should show '<br>' in all modes, not only Textarea